# A Constraint <VERB> a Certain Value

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, idioms

In the context of software programming, I am looking for a verb which expresses a certain relation. Using Merriam Webster online, I have not been able to find what I am looking for, due to lack of a search functionality that matches my needs. I have browsed the verbs and nouns mentioned below with their synonyms and antonyms, but I still haven't found what I'm looking for.

I am looking for a verb that describes the relation between *a condition*, *a check* or *a constraint* on the one hand and a certain *value* on the other hand. This relation can be expressed saying that

> the value *passes* the check
> the value *fulfills* the condition
> the value *complies with* the constraint

The relation would **not** be given if

> the value *violates* the condition

I am looking for a verb that describes the relation in the opposite direction. If you say that *to pass*, *to fulfill*, *to comply with* express the relation of the value to the constraint, I am looking for verbs which express the relation of the constraint to the value. In other words, I want to say this in a sentence having the constraint as subject and the value as object.

I had the following ideas:

> the constraint *rules* the value
> the constraint *governs* the value
> the constraint *curbs* the value
> the constraint *restricts* the value
> the constraint *confines* the value
> the constraint *validates* the value
> the constraint *includes* the value
> the constraint *accepts* the value

But I don't know whether these verbs appropriately express what I mean. I have the feeling none of these options is a good fit. For *to rule*, *to curb*, *to govern*, *to restrict* and *to confine*, I have the feeling that all these verbs imply that "the constraint actively does something to the value", that they imply that the constraint is "changing" or  at least "holding back" the value. But I would like to precisely avoid this implication. Speaking in conceptual metaphors, the constraint IS a GATEKEEPER and the value is PASSING the GATE. But that process does not interact with the value. The constraint IS a RIVERBED and the value FLOWS inside it. The constraint is not a DIKE and the value is not TRYING TO OVERFLOW it. The value does not have an innate "tension" or "energy" and hence does not need "to be held back", it is conceptualized as passive.

For *to include* I do not have this feeling. *to include* correctly expresses that the constraint is describing a certain extension, and the value is to be found within the boundaries of that extension. But I am not sure whether it sounds weird in English to say *a constraint includes a value*. I would rather expect that this expresses a relation of sub-constraints:

> The constraint of being a modern human includes an existentialist lack of meaning.

When it comes to *to validate*, I think that this verb would denote "the process of running the check", and is not limited to the scenario where the value is found to pass the condition.

Personally, *to accept* feels like my best guess, but I don't know if this is an idiomatic way of speaking. I haven't found example sentences in Merriam Webster for this construction.

I am looking for idiomatic ways to express this relation.

Comment: 'Limits' or 'filters' possibly?

Comment: Perhaps the condition constrains the value(s).

Comment: A constraint *allows/permits* some values and *rejects* others; as mentioned it *filters/limits/constrains* values. Vague questions about concepts are harder to answer precisely than specific questions about "what word do I use in the blank in this sentence?"

Comment: @StuartF So far. _permits_ would be my favorite option. Would you make your comment an answer?

Comment: The constraint *governs, confines and restricts* are possible, but all the examples require a following context for a useful answer to be given. I am therefore voting to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: In linear programming, using a graphical model, the region that is bound by the system of constraints is called the 'feasible region'.

Comment: Might as well say _the value does not violate the constraint/condition/whatever_. That's what negation is for, after all. You can't make up a new variable for everything in real language.

Comment: @Greybeard Could you elaborate what context is missing? If the question gets closed, I would like to be able to clarify it. But for that I would need to better understand why it is considered vague.

Comment: If I did, I would be guessing. Why not give an meaningful example sentence (and may be context) with a blank for the verb?

Comment: How about _selects_?

Comment: The constraint dictates / controls the acceptable range of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/constrain)
>
> Constrain:
> to control and limit something

From this definition, you cannot avoid the connotation of controlling or limiting. The idea that a constraint somehow does not interact with the values is inadmissible. There is an inescapable interaction of the two. This means your first list is reasonable. Even *includes* may be acceptable if the constraint is expressed as numerical range.

None of your alternatives need be taken to alter a value; the constraint merely accepts or denies the value (yes or no). In software this is often termed validation.

If “no” is not acceptable to you because it is - as you say - “holding back”, the constraint can have no controlling or limiting effect so may as well not exist. This means that you have sought to redefine *constrain* and have done so in a way that leads you to irresolvable contradiction.

In brief, the constraints that you place on the discussion and meanings limit the flow of relevant ideas to those that mirror your own exhaustively expressed but ultimately self-contradictory notions. These constraints bound the range of acceptable answers. They guide our attempts to answer.

The result of this discussion may be that a constraint **passes** the value (in the two senses of approving it or letting it through).

Comment: But, wait: In _the value passes the constraint_, I  don't see any notion of holding back. Is it me, or is it proving your argument wrong?

Comment: Or is it not idiomatic to say that _a value passes a constraint_?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach if a value does not pass the constraint, it is "held back", in the sense that I think you use the phrase, The constraint may "pass" (accept for further processing) or "hold back" (prevent further processing) the value.

Comment: So you can say both "the value passes the constraint" and "the constraint passes the value"?

Comment: That is neat. I like that. The constraint is acting as a gateway to allow passing; the value passes the constraint. I think it works OK.